# Figure out the last item of a group of items in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine a MySql table like this:

```
---------------------------
ListID | itemID | Item
---------------------------
List_1 | item_1 | Apple
---------------------------
List_1 | item_2 | Orange
---------------------------
List_1 | item_3 | Pear
---------------------------
List_2 | item_1 | Potatoes
---------------------------
List_2 | item_2 | ...
```

I have a `getNextItem()` function which increments the itemID and use a SQL query to get the next item:

```
SELECT * FROM items_tbl
WHERE listID = "$listId"
AND itemID = "$itemID"
LIMIT 1
```

Is there an easy way in SQL to figure out if the item I am getting is the last one of that list?

I could add a column to the table and mark the last item of each list, or I could make another query, get the highest item number and compare with my list the current item, or get the total number of items in the list and keep track of the item number in relation to the list's total... but all these solutions feel like a hack.

Can someone suggest something better in SQL and explain a bit how it works?

Comment: How is "last" and "next" defined? By which column do you sort in order to find the "next" row? Unless you use an ORDER BY there is no such thing as the "next" row.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The function getNextItem() increments the itemID, so "next" means the item with the next itemID within a list. If the current item was Apple, the next item would be Orange and the last item would be pear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not state your DBMS, but the following is an ANSI compliant SQL (should work on PosgreSQL, Oracle, DB2)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT listid, 
           itemid,
           case 
              when lead(itemid) over (partition by listid order by itemid) is null then 'last'
              else 'not_last'
           end as last_flag
    FROM items_tbl
    WHERE listID = 'List_1'
) t
WHERE itemID = 'item_2'
```

**Edit**, the following should work on SQL Server (as that doesn't yet support `lead()`):

```
SELECT listid, 
       itemid,
       case 
         when rn = list_count the 'last'
         else 'not_last'
       end
FROM (
    SELECT listid, 
           itemid,
           row_number() over (partition by listid order by itemid) as rn,
           count(*) over (partition by listid) as list_count
    FROM items_tbl
    WHERE listID = 'List_1'
) t
WHERE itemID = 'item_2'
```

Comment: Thanks. The DBMS is MySql, as in "Imagine a MySql table" ;). I found a solution (see my comment to Jan Vorcak's answer). I don't understand how your solution works. The problem is solved, but I would still like an explanation if you can find the time - as you can tell, my knowledge of SQL is rather basic.

Comment: Sorry, did'nt see the mentioning of MySQL, was looking for a tag. The basic idea is to check if there is a next record based on the sort order you have defined - that's what the `lead` function does. You can read the PostgreSQL manual for a nice introduction to windowing functions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. And sorry I forgot to put it as a tag. Well, since at this time your answer is the only one that can actually does what the question asked, I will select it and upvote Vorcak's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add an autoincrement primary key named id to your table and use nested SQL query to get maximal id of the table

```
SELECT id, ListID, itemID, item, (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name) as max_id from table_name;
```

this will return all columns of your table with one additional column named max_id with the maximal id, so you can check in your app whether max_id == id, if so it's the last column

Comment: Wouldn't that return the last ID from all the lists combined? That said, I think a nested SQL query might be the ticket.

Comment: Using your idea of a subquery, I fixed the SQL request: SELECT *, (
             SELECT MAX(itemID) FROM items_tbl
             WHERE listID= "$listID"
           ) as max_id
FROM items_tbl
WHERE listID = "$listID"
AND itemID= "$itemID"
LIMIT 1; Please fix your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would probably be to, before you Start, get the highest id in each list:

```
Select listID, max(itemID) from mytable group by listID
```

Comment: I'm not sure (we are all learning here anyway), but what if somebody changes the table (add/delete some row), then the result can be other then he wants, or am I wrong?

Comment: If someone changes the table, then this could give the wrong number, yes, but any method I can think of off the top of my head would as well.  The cleanest thing would be to get all the items of a single list at once.  Cache them if you really need just one at a time.

Comment: It would work (my lists don't change), but then I have to keep track of the data in $_SESSION, compare the listID then compare the item number to the total. It's workable, but isn't there a better way?

Comment: If I am going to cache the full lists, I might just as well completely skip the database, use one flat file per list and per language with everything in a PHP array and include the relevant files. That would work too, but it feels wrong. Isn't there a little bit of SQL magic to do that for me?